# firestore, FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: база-данных, firebase, nosql, firestore

При создании записи в firestore с помощью команды:

```
 await firebase.firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc(uid)
    .collection('info')
    .doc(`user_${uid}`)
    .set({
     bill: 10000,
     name,
    });
```

вылетает ошибка: `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`. Если использовать команду

```
await firebase.firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .set({
         bill: 10000,
         name,
        });
```

то ошибок нет. Почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы посмотрите на свои правила Firestore, они должны совпадать

```
`service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}`
```

Если вы не разрешаете чтение, вы можете увидеть эту проблему в клиенте.